# Convert Unicode number to Natural number in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, unicode

Currently I am facing problem with UNICODE character on my Rails 3 project.
In Khmer character number(unicode character) letter "៤" is equal to 4.
I want to compare ៤ >= 3 but can't.
Can anyone suggest me some idea about how to compare that? May be there are some method could convert ៤ to 4 so that I can do compare.
**Note**
I can type ៤ by switching keyboard from Eng to Khm and type 4 as normal.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to compare it as a string (where `"10" < "2"`) or as a number (where `10 > 2`)? If you want to compare strings, your question is about how to translate digits. Otherwise your question is about how to parse numbers in various scripts.

Comment: No I don't want to compare String but I want to compare khmer-number like this "៤> 3" which ៤ is equal to 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the numbers behave in the same way like arabic numerals? Then, you can use this little helper method to convert a Khmer-number string to an integer:

```
# encoding: utf-8

class String
  def to_khmer
    num_string = chars.map{ |c| %w[០ ១ ២ ៣ ៤ ៥ ៦ ៧ ៨ ៩].index(c) || c }.join
    if num_string =~ /\./
      num_string.to_f
    else
      num_string.to_i
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that

```
"s".ord == 115 #=> true
```

---

```
115.chr == "s" #=> true
4.chr.ord == 4 #=> true
```